# Where do you put the function documentation so that it shows up on intellisense?

Tags: c#, .net, intellisense

I'm writing a library and I want to put documentation in my functions so that it will show up in intellisense, kind of like how the intellisense for the built in functions shows descriptions for each of the parameters and for the function itself. How do you put the documentation in? Is it through comments in the function or is it in some separate file?

Comment: If you type /// above a function, it will create a nice little xml header block for you

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use XML comments above the function signature.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="param1">Some Parameter.</param>
    /// <returns>What this method returns.</returns>
```

The [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) plugin can help generate these for you.

Comment: I'd also recommend using StyleCop for Visual Studio to enforce consistent documentation/style through a project.

Comment: @Guard, good suggestion. Inconsistent documentation is sometimes quite the pain.

Comment: type three forward slashes `///` above the function or class and VS will create the boilerplate comment for you.

Answer (score 10):

To auto-generate the three-slash comment section on top of an existing method, just place the cursor on an empty line, right above the method definition and type three forward slashes ("///"). Visual Studio will auto-generate a three-slash comment that corresponds to your method. It will have placeholders for the summary, each parameter (if any) and the return value (if any). You just have to fill-in the blanks.

I would recommend you don't try to write these description blocks by hand and not to copy from one method to another. Third-party tools are also not necessary to generate them (at least in Visual Studio 2010).

Comment: Uh. I assume you meant "I would recommend you try to write these description blocks by hand", without the "don't"?

Answer (score 4):

"**XML Documentation Comments (C# Programming Guide)**
In Visual C# you can create documentation for your code by including XML tags in special comment fields in the source code directly before the code block they refer to."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx

**you can then use Sandcastle to generate chm files too if you want**

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SandcastleMicrosoftCTPOfAHelpCHMFileGeneratorOnTheTailsOfTheDeathOfNDoc.aspx

Comment: Is writing documentation for CSharp the same as writing JavaDocs?

Answer (score 2):

As well as the XML comments you need to enable building the documentation (in the project settings) and keep the generated XML file with the assembly.